# Understanding FileProvider in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I am very noob in Android studio Java apps. so please bear with me on this.
So I would like to save some text data to a .txt file and then share this Text file on a click of a button as attachment for an Email.
I think there are two ways of doing this:
1- Send the .txt file as attachment per email in the background of the activity/App or whatever it is called.
for that way I have already found the SendGmail and I don't know the available stuff in Internet and so on and made Gmail account less secure and stuff but as a noob it just did not work for me so if you can provide me with step-by-step salutation it will be great (it would really really help me if you don't miss out any step even if small and understandable,... thanks in advance)
2- Promote the user to send the Email by using the Intent stuff in android studio java language.
for that according also to the search I have done we need to use the FileProvider service (if I am allowed to call it like that) from the Android Studion Java language.
for that I did the following:

- I Added the Stuff need to be added in the AndroidManifest.xml as following:

```html
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.XXXX.YYYY"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

- and then I created the file_paths.xml file here please support me as I don't exactly know what and how to do it correctly:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

- And now I think I am ready to Save The Text data to a .txt file using this function:

```js
filepath = "AppData";
// in side the on create method i added this permission stuff
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
// of course in the Manifest i also added the user request for Eternal Storage saving stuff
private String SaveToExternal(String fileContent) {
        if (!fileContent.equals("")) {
            File myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), "DataToSend.txt");
            String Out = getExternalFilesDir(filepath) + File.separator + "DataToSeve.txt";
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
                fos.write(fileContent.getBytes());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Unable to save";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Unable to save";
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data to send is prepared and ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //return Out;
            return myExternalFile.getPath();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data to send is not available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return "Unable to save";
        }
    }
```

here if you can provide me with more information on how really to select where to save what it will be great (sorry for asking too much)

- now the .txt file is there I just need to attach it and send it per Email of the App user: I used the following Code for that:

```js
private void sendEmail(String Body, String FilePath) {
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your Email Body is: " + Body,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            // First copy the File from internal to External storage:
            // File dst = new File(StringPath);
            // exportFile(new File(FilePath), dst);
            // Then Share it now

            // This one was working:
            Uri Pathtosend = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.example.XXXX.YYYY",new File(FilePath));
            
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your Uri is: " + Pathtosend,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TTba.setText(Pathtosend.toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                    //.setType("message/rfc822")
                    //.setType("text/plain")
                    .setType("*/*")
                    .setData(new Uri.Builder().scheme("mailto").build())
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"XXXX YYYY <XYZ@gmail.com>"})
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject")
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dear Sir/Madem" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "I would like to ......")
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Pathtosend)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email with");

            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                grantUriPermission(packageName, Pathtosend, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            try {
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"I am at the try of send Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(chooser);
            } catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I am at the Catch of send Email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ComponentName emailApp = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager());
                ComponentName unsupportedAction = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.fallback/.Fallback");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Results of ComponentName: " + emailApp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (emailApp != null && !emailApp.equals(unsupportedAction))
                    try {
                        // Needed to customise the chooser dialog title since it might default to "Share with"
                        // Note that the chooser will still be skipped if only one app is matched
                        Intent chooser1 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email with");
                        startActivity(chooser1);
                        return;
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
                    }

                Toast
                        .makeText(this, "Couldn't find an email app and account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unable to create Pathtosend",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

- So after I have those two I can call it when the button is clicked and so on like this:

```js
rv = "Testing stuff that need to be saved to Text file and then attached";
DataPathFile = SaveToExternal(rv);
sendEmail(rv,DataPathFile);
```

so guy now comes the problem with this method I am using. it is working on the Emulator and SAMUSNG with Android version 8.0.0 but not working on my SAMSUNG with Android version 11.
in my build.gradle i have:

```js
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.XXXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

I think the problem is with where the file is saved and how to know the exact path of the file and how to dynamically update the file path in xml or java or wherever it should be updated.

Thanks a lot for your help and support :)

Comment: Please remove the code where you create a txt file. Its irrelevant. Just start your post telling that you have a path to a txt file.

Comment: I dont have a path and this is my problem i am somehow unable to get the correct path. from one Android version to another the path is changing

Comment: If you managed you save a text in a txt file then you know its path. Does not matter if the path is different in different versions. Then if you saved you know where the file is.

Comment: Ok looking at my code (in which i still need an answer). I saved the text file like this: getExternalFilesDir(filepath) + File.separator + "DataToSeve.txt"; so very simple question what should i write in the XML file to find this Path?

Comment: I do not understand your question. With writing to a file you cannot find a path. But you determined your path with `getExternalFilesDir(filepath) + File.separator + "DataToSeve.txt"` So that is your path.

Comment: File file = new FIle( getExternalFilesDir(filepath),  "DataToSeve.txt"; String path = file.getAbsolutePath(); But.... What is filePath? The only thing you can put there is a folder name.

Comment: so after i got this information, i need to use it here: Uri Pathtosend = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,"com.example.XXXX.YYYY",new File(FilePath)); according to Documentation but that is not working for me that is why i am asking this only did work for me when i added the followin to my XML file: <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/> which is according to my think  wrong as it is working for some mobile phones and not all so can you help me what should i write in my XML to get this simple clear saved location code to work?

Comment: You cannot put such names in the paths xml file. You should google a bit for examples as there are so many top find on the internet. And if you post code or files then post them in your post and not in comments. Please remove the Run code spippet and othe buttons from your post. They do not work.

Comment: So till now i got no answer so the question can you help me? if Yes then please provide me with the correct way to do the task (attach a text file to a user Email app) if no then no need for the discussion as: i have already searched the internet and did not find a solution for my problem and the code is there not to run just to show what i have done.  so my question then what should i write in the XML file then? if you know show me

Comment: I know. Everybody knows. Examples all over the place. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Comment: `Thanks a lot for your help and support :)`

Comment: still no support if you can answer me just do that mate i am stuck here

Comment: `You cannot put such names in the paths xml file` Now which 'name' did you put there? And is that a name? No. It's a path. Further you did nothing with my first remark. So why should i bother helping you?

Comment: So as you can see i dont even know what should i do with your first comment (already said am new to this) and the code i posted is to show what i have done so someone can correct that and not only suggest what can be done. yes i should not write such names but what should i then write? still waiting for a direct answer as you can see so telling me what not to do is not enough.

Comment: `name="/storage/emulated/0" ` You should make it a name. Now it is a path. Any name will do. Even `name="user2573266"`-).

Comment: And can you remove those Run code snippet buttons?

Comment: So adding a name is not working for me (and that is the question) i don't know why can you help me??

Comment: Ohh man you and that snippet buttons how can i remove then i dont know how to do that